# BASH: Sort array of files with crazy names

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting, find

Problem:

Need to sort array before operating on them with function.

First, array is loaded with files:

```
unset a i
counter=1
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    a[i++]="$file"
done < <(find $DIR -type f -print0)
```

Next, each member of array is sent to function

```
for f in "${a[@]}"
do
   func_hash "$f"
   [ $(expr $counter % 20) -eq 0 ] && printf "="
   counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

Somehow a sort needs to be thrown into the above for loop. Have looked
through the SO posts on sorting arrays but somehow my crazy file names
cause issues when I try to tack on a sort.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Bubnoff

**UPDATE:** Here's code with sort:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    func_hash "$file"
    [ $(expr $counter % 20) -eq 0 ] && printf "="
    counter=$((counter + 1))
done < <(find $DIR -type f -print0 | sort -z +1 -1)
```

It's sorting by full path rather than file name. Any ideas on how to
sort by file name given that the path is needed for the function?

**UPDATE 2:** Decided to compromise.

My main goal was to avoid temp files using sort. GNU sort can write back to the original
file with its '-o' option so now I can:

```
sort -o $OUT -t',' -k 1 $OUT
```

Anyone have a more 'elegant' solution ( whatever that means ).

**SOLVED** See jw013's answer below. Thanks man!

Comment: We need the fileNames and the required sort order (examples that capture a few regular and all unusual cases). Good Luck.

Comment: you also didn't link to the  SO posts you tried.  My first instinct would be to pipe the `find` output to `sort` within the `<()`, did that not work with the funky files?

Comment: nhed - no it didn't. I'll try it again and post the error.

Comment: shellter - Extremely long file names with spaces and commas. Alpha sort.

Comment: Decided to bag sort on the fly. Have decided to do a 'sort -o'. Wanted to avoid a tmp file. Open to suggestion.

Comment: This option is available on OSX xServe, so is thankfully portable to the target.

Comment: I don't quite get the problem which got "solved" by sorting a file instead of stream.

Comment: 'sort -o' overwriting input worked in 7th Edition UNIX back in the late 70s; it has always been supported and is required by POSIX.

Comment: Paulo ~ problem was: output file needed to be sorted without temp file. Originally, I was hoping to populate it with pre-sorted input. Used sort -o instead on the file.

Comment: Jonathan ~ Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
while IFS= read -r -d/ && read -r -d '' file; do
    a[i++]="$file"
done < <(find "$DIR" -type f -printf '%f/%p\0' | sort -z -t/ -k1 )
```

Rationale:

- I make the assumption that `/` is never a legal character within a file name (which seems reasonable on most *nix filesystems since it is the path separator).
- The `-printf` is used to print the file name without leading directories, then then full file name with path, separated by `/`.  The sort takes place on the first field separated by `/` which should be the full file name without path.
- The `read` is modified to first use `/` as a delimiter to throw out the pathless file name.

**side note**

Any POSIX shell should support the modulo operator as part of its arithmetic expansion.  You can replace line with the call to external command `expr` in the second loop with

```
[ $(( counter % 20 )) -eq 0 ] ...
```

Comment: Kind of. See my update above. Find returns full path and sort 'sorts' by fullpath. I need to sort by filename while retaining full path in the loop, in order to pass full path to function.

Comment: Completely brilliant! Works perfectly. It's significantly slower than a separate 'sort' though. Thanks!

Comment: I take back my comment regarding speed. Several runs show it averaging about the same speed. Thanks again!